# forward snmptraps with snmptrapd to second host

Tags: snmp, udp, ip-forwarding

I have a setup with snmptrapd listening on udp:162 to receive snmp traps.
They are then processed on this host with snmptt.

I am now in the need that I need to forward those traps *additionally* to another host, but also process them with snmptrapd and snmptt on the current host.

There is no possibility to set up a primary host to use samplicator or iptables to forward them to both hosts. I need to have the primary server send them in original packets to the second host.

Because of snmptrapd listening on udp 162 it is also not possible to start samplicator on the first host to duplicate them because how can snmptrapd listen otherwise on the host.

Is there a possibility with snmptrapd to forward them to another host running snmptrapd with a traphandler?

I currently have one default traphandler configured:

```
# For snmptt daemon mode
traphandle default /usr/local/centreon/bin/snmptthandler --ini=/etc/snmp/centreon_traps/snmptt.ini
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add a

```
forward default host_you_want_to_redirect
```